# SDL2 Undefined symbol for ARM64 Architecture

Tags: c, macos, gcc, sdl-2

I have tested multiple instances of SDL2 code with tutorials and my gcc compilation string and everything works fine, but when I start trying to use the library I start getting weird errors for my M1 mac.

Here is error:

```
enceladus:doomengine$ gcc hello.c -o prog -lSDL2 -ldl
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SDL_SetVideoMode", referenced from:
      _main in hello-5bdcd2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Ok, removed all code and just used small example:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Define window size */
#define W 608
#define H 480

static SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    surface = SDL_SetVideoMode(W, H, 32, 0);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. "Reproducible" means something that has **everything** one needs to reproduce your problem (like `#include` directives) and "minimal" means there is **nothing** more than that  (like your entire program after the call to `SDL_SetVideoMode`).

Comment: “First I declare the prototype” Don’t do that. Find where are the headers of that third-party library, and `#include` the header which defines that function. The correct answer depends on your OS, not just on the CPU. If you’re building this on OSX, one possible way to install that library is building it from source code: https://www.dennis-schneider.com/blog/how-to-install-sdl2-on-mac-os-x/ Another possible method is installing the library with brew package manager: https://brew.sh/

Comment: The true beauty of the [mre] (MRE) is that its a n exercise in isolating the bug and the more you isolate the bug, the less noise it has to hide in. Eventually the bug becomes obvious and usually you can squish it yourself. When you can't, that's when Stack Overflow becomes useful.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Great ideas.  Just a sec I will compress down to smaller sample and see what happens.

Comment: Anyway, there is no `SDL_SetVideoMode` in SDL2. There is such function in SDL1. [What happened to SDL_SetVideoMode() in SDL2](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/what-happened-to-sdl-setvideomode-in-sdl2/19672/2). You decide what to do with this information.

Comment: facepalm. This is the worst face plant ever accomplished on stack overflow.

Comment: Not even close. You don't get to see the truly bad face plants because they get deleted very quickly. Good on you for self answering so that some good can come of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Used wrong library.  Using SDL2 for SDL1 deprecated commands. Thanks where's my share.